# How to add delay to document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, delay, getelementbyid

I have this:

I'm trying to load this js code, value.id corresponds to an element that is detected after loading page. But actually this code is running before the element is loaded and im having this error:

Cannot read property 'nodeType' of null

I want to add something like delay on the `document.getElementById(value.id)`

I tried this, but nothing:

```
    const area = setTimeout(document.getElementById(value.id), 4000);
    Count.on(area, counter => {
    ...
```

and:

```
function setDelay() {
  document.getElementById(value.id);
}
setTimeout(setDelay, 4000);
const area = setDelay
Count.on(area, counter => {
...
```

both giving same error, any idea??

Comment: You can use `window.onload` to set a function to be called after the page loads...

Comment: Also what is `value.id`?

Comment: Thanks, how you recommend me to use that window.onload using the piece of code i submitted at the top of the post. Thanks!!

Comment: all the code is working perfect, i have all the values declared. I only need to know how to set up the delay :D

Comment: it depends...what is `value.id`?

Comment: is `value` a global variable?

Comment: value.id is a value that my customer will setup, not me. My customer will create a element, then add the value he wants. Then my script will take that value, and get the data using that value. That's why i have to add a delay.

Comment: yes, we can say its a global variable.

Comment: So u are dependent on user input? Then you don't need a delay you just need to tap into the event triggered by the user...?

Comment: No, lets say i add some fields to my customer. And my customer can decide to activate the function on some element. He adds a id to that element. And my script takes that id, and executes that. If i run the code not on loading page, after loading page works perfect. But i need also to be capable to run that after loading page, because if there's some data saved in that field i want to read it.

Comment: Use `value.onload` to set a function that is called when value is loaded, i-e, when your customer would setup the value element.

Comment: Hey Saud thanks, that makes sense. Any example?? Thanks!

Comment: `value.onload = function() { const area = document.getElementById(value.id); //... };` ... try something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all, i solved it with this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put code inside one function and call it `setDelay` function

```
function setDelay() {
    const area = document.getElementById(value.id);
    Count.on(area, counter => {
    ...
}
setTimeout(setDelay, 4000);
```

`setTimeout` will not return anything to caller.

Comment: Hello thanks Vivek for you answer. Tried but still getting the error. Another idea?

Comment: @K3ny1 You should check `value.id` value OR may be you can use `setDelay.bind(this, value.id)` and change `function setDelay(valuesId)`